# Действие при клике на "Читать далее"

Tags: jquery, css

Есть инфо-блок. При нажатии на кнопку "Читать далее" (с указателем вниз), выезжает подробный текст инфо-блока, кнопка должна менятся на "Свернуть" и появляется стрелка вверх. Как реализовать плавную замену текста кнопки "Читать далее" на "Свернуть" и замену стрелки вниз на вверх с помощью jquery/css? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var s = 'Свернуть'
 $('.text').click(function() {
          $(this).animate({
                opacity: 0
              }, 500, function() {
                $(this).attr('value', s).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                  }, 500,function(){if(s=='Свернуть')s='Читать далее';else s='Свернуть';})
                })
})
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="submit" name="text" class="text" value="Читать далее">
```

Суть проста в animate *пихаете* css атрибуты которые вам нужны